# Is it possible to use arrow keys in OCaml interpreter?

Tags: ocaml, interpreter, arrow-keys, ledit

Everytime I use these keys in the interpreter I keep getting symbols like this appearing:

```
[[D^[[C
```

I'm using Linux Mint 12 in ZSH, however I'm getting the same result in Ubuntu with bash.
Also, same thing in ssh.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The stock OCaml toplevel doesn't have line editing built in.  I use `rlwrap`:

```
$ cat bin/ocaml
#!/bin/sh
exec rlwrap /usr/local/bin/ocaml "$@"
```

Using the toplevel without something like this is quite painful, in my opinion!

Other possibilities are to run the toplevel under emacs (a popular choice, I think), or to use [utop](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/utop/).  I haven't used utop, but it sounds cool.

Comment: utop is very cool.  In addition to supporting basic line editing (arrow keys to move the cursor around, history) utop also supports fairly robust context-sensitive completion.  For example, L<tab>.i<tab> will complete to List.iter (assuming the stdlib is the only thing in scope).

Comment: Wow Indeed utop is very cool. It needed some packages to install but wow! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 20):

Another option is to use:

`ledit ocaml`

Although I prefer utop over anything else myself.

Comment: I added this to my .bashrc: `alias ocaml="ledit ocaml"`